# creating batch file to run sql query in sql developer and store result in excel sheet

Tags: sql, oracle, batch-file

I am creating a batch file that will be executed daily at a specific time. The batch file will execute a .sql file. The .sql contains a complex select statement. I have created the sql file using Sql Developer. Also the output of the sql must be stored in an excel sheet with name as todays date.

I have read posts related to batch file to run the sql script but have not found clear answers. I am completely new to batch files.
Thanks

Comment: Just to make sure: you **are** using Oracle, right?

Answer (score 0):

try to use **bcp** command http://sqlfool.com/2008/12/bcp-basics/ with queryout option

Comment: BCP is for SQL Server. As akzhere is using SQL Developer it's probably a good guess that he/she is using Oracle.

Comment: Ya that's right. I am using oracle. so any other analogus command for oracle. And i am a guy...:P

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name do you have any solution. I have looked for answers but couldn't find anything relevant